# How to convert matrix with integer values to matrix binary values in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm trying to create a MATLAB script that converts an 100x100 matrix of positive integers to their unsigned binary values.
Example matDec=[1,2;1,2] converted to matBin=[00000001,00000010;00000001,00000010].

I tried something like:

```
BinI=int2bit(I,8);
```

where `I` is the initial matrix and `BinI` is the matrix.

But I got an 800x100 matrix as a result, meaning that the bits of each element got split into 8 elements.

Comment: "string of bits" you say, which should have length 8 right? So it is the right size?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes , each values varies from 0-255 , so 8 bits is the right size.The problem is that each string is divided into 8 different elements

Comment: No, a string is a "char array", an array of individual characters.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `convertCharsToStrings`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried to , but all i got was a single string.I also tried this command inside a for  loop , for each individual element.

Comment: What is “a binary matrix”? Please describe what you expected to get out. Numbers are stored in a binary format in the computer, they are just displayed as decimal. Do you want to display the numbers in binary format?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've just added an example.I want to convert each matrix element from decimal to binary

Comment: Ok, but what is “00000010”? There is no such thing in MATLAB. That would be interpreted as the number 10, but you don’t want that. Is your output currently equal to `['00000001','00000010';'00000001','00000010']`, which is a 2x16 char array?

Comment: What is this `int2bin` you are using? Is it a function on the File Exchange? There is no such function in MATLAB. There is a `dec2bin` though.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried a couple of things and managed to get a 10000x8 char array as a result.Is there any way to reshape it to a 100X100X8 char array ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to reshape it using `reshape(A,100,100,8)`. The 10,000 dimension will be split into 100x100 dimensions, and if `A` was obtained with `dec2bin`, they’ll be in the same order as the numeric matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let be

```
A1 =
     4    -2     4   -10
     5     3   -10    -8
     5    -7    -5     7
```

then

```
A2=dec2bin(A1)
A2 =
  12×8 char array
    '00000100'
    '00000101'
    '00000101'
    '11111110'
    '00000011'
    '11111001'
    '00000100'
    '11110110'
    '11111011'
    '11110110'
    '11111000'
    '00000111'
```

You are right, although in the command line the result looks as if each line is just one element, the type is `char` so each inidividual character is an actually a single element.

A way to obtain the sought matrix with same size as the input is using command `string`

```
sz1=size(A1);
reshape(string(dec2bin(A1)),sz1)
 = 
  3×4 string array
    "00000100"    "11111110"    "00000100"    "11110110"
    "00000101"    "00000011"    "11110110"    "11111000"
    "00000101"    "11111001"    "11111011"    "00000111"
```

Command `string` was introduced in MATLAB version 2016b.

There's no command `string` in previous versions.

Comment: You can use `cellstr` here instead of `string` in any version of MATLAB, you'll end up with a cell array of chars instead of a string array